# Terraform enable specific VMs via command line

Tags: terraform

Within my Terraform files or tooling I'm trying to control whether specific VMs (modules) get enabled or not with terraform apply plan.  Is there a way to do this with Terraform init or apply parameters?  Or do I just need to create a Python master script that writes terraform *.tf files to enable or disable specific VMs?  Here is an example, in my **main.tf** file I have several different VMs.  I would like to have terraform invoke at command line to specify which VMs get enabled or not.  Reason for this is I have a free community Cyber Range terraform project and the cost incurred could be large.  I'd like to have the options for user flexibility and more automated for a user invoking which modules get enabled (rather than commenting out a Terraform file manually).  Trying to make it more automated to dynamically enable specific VMs/Modules.  This could more easily just be done with a Python CLI tool that gives a user a menu of which ones to enable and then controls Terraform.  But would be cool to know if Terraform can do this natively with features.

```
##########################################################
## Create Primary DC VM & AD Forest
##########################################################
module "dc1-vm" {
  source                        = "../modules/dc1-vm"
  resource_group_name           = module.network.out_resource_group_name
  location                      = var.location
  prefix                        = var.prefix
  subnet_id                     = module.network.dc_subnet_subnet_id
  active_directory_domain       = "${var.prefix}.local"
  active_directory_netbios_name = var.prefix
  dc1private_ip_address         = var.dc1private_ip_address
  #network_security_group_id     = "${azurerm_network_security_group.vm_security_group.id}"
  admin_username = var.admin_username
  admin_password = var.admin_password
}

##########################################################
## Create Secondary Domain Controller VM & Join domain
##########################################################
/*module "dc2-vm" {
  source                        =  "../modules/dc2-vm"
  resource_group_name           = "${module.dc1-vm.out_resource_group_name}"
  location                      = "${var.location}"
  dcavailability_set_id         = "${module.dc1-vm.out_dcavailabilityset}"
  prefix                        = "${var.prefix}"
  subnet_id                     = "${module.network.dc_subnet_subnet_id}"
  active_directory_domain       = "${var.prefix}.local"
  active_directory_username     = "${var.admin_username}"
  active_directory_password     = "${var.admin_password}"
  active_directory_netbios_name = "${var.prefix}"
  dc2private_ip_address         = "${var.dc2private_ip_address}"
  admin_username                = "${var.admin_username}"
  admin_password                = "${var.admin_password}"
  domainadmin_username          = "${var.domainadmin_username}"
}*/

##########################################################
## Create the AriaCloud Adversary 1 
##########################################################
module "adversary1-vm" {
  source              = "../modules/adversary1-vm"
  resource_group_name = module.network.out_resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  prefix              = var.prefix
  subnet_id           = module.network.user2_subnet_subnet_id
}

### Create Windows 10 Pro VM-1
module "win10-vm-1" {
  source                    = "../modules/win10-vm-1"
  resource_group_name       = module.dc1-vm.out_resource_group_name
  location                  = var.location
  prefix                    = var.prefix
  endpoint1_machine_name    = var.endpoint1_machine_name
  endpoint1_username        = var.endpoint1_username
  subnet_id                 = module.network.user1_subnet_subnet_id
  active_directory_domain   = "${var.prefix}.local"
  active_directory_username = var.admin_username
  active_directory_password = var.admin_password
  admin_username            = var.admin_username
  admin_password            = var.admin_password
  vmcount                   = var.vmcount
}


module "win10-vm-2" {
  source                    = "../modules/win10-vm-2"
  resource_group_name       = module.dc1-vm.out_resource_group_name
  location                  = var.location
  prefix                    = var.prefix
  endpoint2_machine_name    = var.endpoint2_machine_name
  endpoint2_username        = var.endpoint2_username
  subnet_id                 = module.network.user1_subnet_subnet_id
  active_directory_domain   = "${var.prefix}.local"
  active_directory_username = var.admin_username
  active_directory_password = var.admin_password
  admin_username            = var.admin_username
  admin_password            = var.admin_password
  vmcount                   = var.vmcount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the Resource Targeting feature in Terraform which looks like it fits the requirement:
https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/resource-targeting-in-terraform